# How to detect current web page or element direction (rtl/ltr) or any other attribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, right-to-left

How can i read any attribute that currently effects an element that is not necessarily style? one such attribute would be "dir".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently I had similar problem, you can get element's property with [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) and [element.currentStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) methods:

```
    var elem = document.getElementById('test');
    if (window.getComputedStyle) { // all browsers
        cs = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue('direction');
    } else {
        cs = elem.currentStyle.direction; // IE5-8
    }
    alert(cs);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVpBR/2/) ; [compatibility info](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#style)

Answer (score 0):

These are generally reflected as properties on the element instance. `dir` is, for example, as are most others. Some have slightly renamed names (`htmlFor` instead of `for`, `className` instead of `class`), but for the most part it's 1:1 (`target` for `target`, `action` for `action`, ...).

References:

- [`dir` in the DOM2 HTML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-52460740)
- [`dir` in the HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-dir)

Answer (score 0):

Also easy to get variable in JavaScript:

```
var direction = document.dir;
```

in case of rtl its "rtl"