# JavaScript LTR/RTL detection on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, css, nested, detection, right-to-left

How can I detect the text direction of an element?

The text direction can be set in a HTML document to any element or a parent thereof.
You can do that through the elements *dir* property, or through the *direction* property of CSS. And the browser can be set to LTR or RTL as a whole as well, so you might have RTL styling without any property set.

```
<body dir=rtl>
  <div dir=ltr style="direction:rtl" class="western">
    <span id=whatAmI></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Now how can I detect, in javascript, whether the whatAmI span is RTL or LTR aligned?

I'm thinking of adding an invisible element and requesting its position, but it feels like there must  be better ways to get this info.

Comment: can i ask what the point of it? why do you want to know the direction of an element?

Comment: @roland generally it toggels on click of the button or browser language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect current web page or element direction (rtl/ltr) or any other attribute in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957533/how-to-detect-current-web-page-or-element-direction-rtl-ltr-or-any-other-attri)

Comment: Yes you have to use `getComputedStyle`: https://jsfiddle.net/mu48px9r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('whatAmI')).direction;
```

Comment: Ah indeed. Never thought of this as (CSS) styling.